# Issue with HTTP.Body parameters - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this code, I need to pass parameters by BUDDY, but I get a "rare" error. Can anybody help me? THX!!

**This is the error**

> > Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda33f4cd80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:.../users.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:.../users.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response})

```
func registerUser(currentUser: Users, IsRegistered : (isRegistered: Bool, messageString: String) -> ()) {

let REGISTER_URL = "users.php?"

var bodyParams: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()
bodyParams["firstName"] = currentUser.getFirstName()
bodyParams["lastName"] = currentUser.getLastName()
bodyParams["gender"] = currentUser.getGender()
bodyParams["birthday"] = currentUser.getBirthday()

let urlAppend = createFullURL(REGISTER_URL, urlParams: Dictionary())

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlAppend)!)

let loginString = "\(currentUser.getEmail()):\(currentUser.getPassword())"
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = "Basic \(loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength))"
let headerParams: Dictionary<String, String> = ["Authorization": base64LoginString]

for (key, value) in headerParams{
    request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
}

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//
// The problem is the following 4 lines, if I tell, there is no error, but of course, I can not register a user
//

do {

    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(bodyParams, options: [])

} catch {

    IsRegistered(isRegistered: false, messageString: "Error al parsear los datos.")

}

request.HTTPMethod = METHOD_GET

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

    if (error != nil) {

        // ERROR HERE //      
        // ERROR HERE //
        // ERROR HERE //
        print(error)

    } else {

        ...
    }

    }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [HTTPBody](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlrequest/2011390-httpbody)

> **httpBody**
>
> This data is sent as the message body of the request, as in done in an HTTP POST request.

When you use `request.HTTPMethod = "GET"`, you can not use `HTTPBody` to append your `&k=v` pairs.
Add parameters to the URL string.

Comment: @mxcl link is working for me, any way I will fix it.

Comment: Indeed, works again, minus one undone!… however, the half-life of a link is 3 hours (!) so it's always better to copy and paste providing a link as a citation. IMO. Not just MO.

Comment: Thanks @mxcl, But what do you mean by IMO and MO ?!!

Comment: Roughly 5 years late to the party but it's probably "in my opinion" and "my opinion".